# Best way to make Custom Field Mandatory based on field's value?

Tags: custom-field, validation-rule

I have a requirement to make one of the field required while closing case?

For this requirement, can I make field required at page layout level?
If so, does it throw error also when creating case?

For the above requirement making field required by validation rule is best possible solution or can I have any other alternative solutions?

Comment: Validation rule would be best possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a field required at page layout only restricts if the record is being created through that page.

So it depends on your application and requirement. If there are other places from where the records can be still created then it wont be a good option from data consistency point.

I would prefer validation rule, as it will be one backend logic which will get fired for all record creation irrespective of from where the record is being created.

Just FYI : Additionally you can bypass validation rules by creating a Custom setting flow and use this custom setting whenever a validation rule, this is helpful in some scenarios.

Comment: Requirement is to make a custom field (e.g Type field) mandatory while closing the case object record, we didnt want those fields value at the time of case record is created.